# else section ignored in script

Tags: .net, powershell

Having some trouble getting an `if`/`else` statement to work. When I have it in place, the loop never continues on to the `else` and just processes all files based on the `if`. Is there something I'm missing?

What I'm trying to do is have any recordings for extension 201 and 205 just get copied and not emailed, and the remainder to be emailed them copied. The code below will run through all the files but if there is something there for either of those it just keeps the same `$ext` variable for all subsequent ones.

```
#Setting up log rotation
$LogDate = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd
$Logfile = "C:\Scripts\Inbound-$LogDate.log"
$logcount = 10

function LogWrite {
   Param ([string]$logstring)

   Add-Content $Logfile -Value $logstring
}

function Get-TimeStamp {
    return "[{0:MM/dd/yy} {0:HH:mm:ss}]" -f (Get-Date)
}

#$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$SourceFolder = '\\fileserver\Recordings\autorecords'
# Delimiters for use on breaking apart the text strings
$delim = '-'
$delim2 = '@'

#email Information
$Port = "25"
$SMTPUsername = "domain\username"

#Secure string for password to avoid plaintext passwords
$EncryptedPasswordFile = "C:\Scripts\password.txt"
$EmailCredential = New-Object -TypeName Management.Automation.PSCredential($SMTPUsername, (Get-Content $EncryptedPasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString))

#Once sent, send emailed files here to be purged at a later date
$ProcFolder = '\\fileserver\Recordings\processed'
#List of extensions & Associated email addresses
$extensions = @{
    '999' = 'bill@test.com';
    '201' = 'Dude@test.com';
    '203' = 'PersoN@test.com';
    '204' = 'emailaddress';
    '205' = 'emailaddress';
}
Push-Location $SourceFolder
$File = Get-ChildItem $SourceFolder -Name *.wav -Recurse -File
$File | Foreach-object {
    $nameArray = $_.Split($delim)
    $newName = $nameArray[2]+" "+($nameArray[0].substring(0,8))
    $ext = $nameArray[3]
    #If statement will just move recordings to 201 or 205 to the processed folder instead of leaving them in the recordings
    if (($ext = '201') -or ($ext = '205')) {
        Move-Item -Path $SourceFolder\$_ -Destination $ProcFolder
        LogWrite "$(Get-TimeStamp) Moved recording $_ for $ext to processed"
    } else {
        $callerID = $nameArray[2]
        $Datestamp = ($nameArray[0].Substring(0, 8))
        $emailAddress = $extensions[$ext]
        $FirstNameArray = $emailAddress.Split($delim2)
        $FirstName = $FirstNameArray[0]
        $SMTPProperties = @{
            To = $emailAddress
            From = 'voicemails@test.com'
            Body = 'New Call Recording'
            BodyAsHtml = $true
            subject = "Call Recording on $Datestamp from ($CallerID) to $FirstName"
            smtpserver = 'mailserver'
            attachment = $_
            Port = '25'
        }

        Send-MailMessage @SMTPProperties
        LogWrite "$(Get-TimeStamp) Sent email to $emailAddress"
        Move-Item -Path $SourceFolder\$_ -Destination $ProcFolder
        LogWrite "$(Get-TimeStamp) Moved recording $_ for $ext to processed"  
    }
}
```

Comment: `=` is an assignment, to compare use `-eq`

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate - the dupe target is not an exact duplicate, but it illuminates the reason behind why your code fails your expectations